# JDialog is never garbage collected

Tags: java, swing, garbage-collection, jdialog

Why does the following code never garbage collect the JDialog instance ?
The instance X has no reference and the dialog has been disposed.

```
public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable {
    test();

    Runtime.getRuntime().gc();
}

public static void test() throws Throwable {
    X x = new X();
    x.setVisible(true);
    x.dispose();
}

public static class X extends JDialog {

    public X() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    protected void finalize() throws Throwable {
        System.out.println("destroyed !");
        super.finalize();
    }

}

}
```

Thank you

Comment: Just general advise: You can neither expect `gc()` to perform garbage collection nor `finalize()` being called. You should never have to rely on `gc()`, there is just no need. You should never never never rely on `finalize()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is (and some of the answers are) mixing two things, garbage collection and finalization. Runtime.getRuntime().gc() is just a hint that the collection should run and it’s very likely that the Dialog has been collected afterward (there’s still no guaranty). But this does not mean that the finalizer will run. The virtual machine will avoid running finalize methods as much as it can.

There is another issue with your test program. JDialog without a parent forces Swing to create an anonymous Frame as parent behind the scenes which will stay alive with unpredictable results (AWT runs within a different thread).

Try this test program:

```
import java.lang.ref.WeakReference;

import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable {
    WeakReference<JDialog> ref = test();

    Runtime.getRuntime().gc();
    System.out.println(ref.get()==null? "collected": "still flying around");
  }

  public static WeakReference<JDialog> test() throws Throwable {
      JDialog d = new JDialog(new JFrame());
      WeakReference<JDialog> ref = new WeakReference<JDialog>(d);
      d.setVisible(true);
      d.dispose();
      d.getOwner().dispose();
      return ref;
  }
}
```

This works for me.

An alternative to Runtime.getRuntime().gc() is:

```
try {
    byte[] b = new byte[Integer.MAX_VALUE];
} catch(OutOfMemoryError err) {}
```

as the vm guarantees performing gc before OOME (might not work with 64bit vms ;-) ).

Answer (score 1):

The GC calls can't be expected at the specific time. It is called randomly or when there is full memory allocated by the JVM.

P.S. Your `x.dispose();` don't call the GC. It may just mark that this object can be collected.

Comment: Runtime.getRuntime().gc(); should call the gc ?

Comment: It may call, but there is no guaranty that the object will be collected when you want. Anyway, you should only pay attention to that method when you work with huge amount of data.

Answer (score 1):

As was said before - you cannot expect GC at the specific time. But you can "force" it by filling up the memory.

try this code, it fills memory after disposing your class. It allocates a lot of Longs in loop but any bigger class would be better. (thought thi suffice on my defaults)

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable {
        test();

        Runtime.getRuntime().gc();
    }

    public static void test() throws Throwable {
        X x = new X();
        x.setVisible(true);
        x.dispose();
        //Fill memory:
        for (int i = 0; i < Integer.MAX_VALUE; ++i) {
            Long l = 10L;
        }
    }

    public static class X extends JDialog {

        public X() {
            super();
        }

        @Override
        protected void finalize() throws Throwable {
            System.out.println("destroyed !");
            super.finalize();
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

dialog the first one is never GC'ed, and there are some bugs with that, but unfor***, bugsParade is freeze now

dispose() has nothing to do with GC http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#dispose%28%29

Comment: I know dispose has nothing to do with GC. But if you call dispose, then system resources should be removed and when I call Runtime.getRuntime().gc(); the gc should finalize the dialog instance ?

Comment: @Joachim Sauer thank you for link to Java6, @ Benjamin Leclerc if you are familair with JProfiler, then you can simple way see how JVM instance works with Object and Methods and with live Object, there are some bug with API for JDialog: DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE (defined in WindowConstants): Automatically hide and dispose the dialog after invoking any registered WindowListener objects.

Answer (score 0):

The JVM stops before the garbage collection needs to be run. Therefore the `JDialog` is never garbage collected and thus never finalized.